# Dealing with more than one Optional parameter

Tags: maple

I have a procedure

```
f:=proc(x,option1,option2) ... end proc;
```

In my case `option1` is always an integer and `option2` is either a list or something else (including integer). Both options are optional, so these commands work as expected:

```
f(x);
f(x,3);
f(x,4,[1,2]);
f(x,5,3);
f(x,6,expand);
```

But if `option1` isn't specified then I don't know an easy way to deal with it since Maple doesn't allow the usage like

```
f(x,,3);
f(x,,[1,2]);
```

I can make it understand

```
f(x,[1,2]);
```

but I still have a problem with

```
f(x,3);
```

since it's not clear if `3` is `option1` or `option2`. I can rewrite the code to understand function calls in this format

```
f(x,[1,option1],[2,option2]);
f(x,[1,option1]);
f(x,[2,option2]);
```

but I'm curious if there is a simpler way to achieve that since for some Maple functions (like `plot`) the order of most options doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the plotting commands use Maple's more modern [argument-processing](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=argument_processing) to manage procedure options.

In particular most options to plotting commands are provided as so-called [keyword](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=argument_processing#keyword) options. That automatically provides the functionlity in which the location (of such options) doesn't matter.

For example,

```
f:=proc(v, 
        {ord::{integer,NoUserValue}:=':-NoUserValue'},
        {special::{integer,list,NoUserValue}:=':-NoUserValue'});

  print(':-ord'=ord, ':-special'=special);

end proc:

f(x);

    ord = NoUserValue, special = NoUserValue

f(x,ord=3);

         ord = 3, special = NoUserValue

f(x,special=5);

         ord = NoUserValue, special = 5

f(x,special=5,ord=3);

               ord = 3, special = 5

f(x,ord=3,special=5);

               ord = 3, special = 5
```

As you've noticed, you [logically] cannot use multiple *positional/ordered" parameters if both have the same type and some earlier ones are missing.

If you really wanted you could make one of those options into a [positional parameter](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=argument_processing#positional), although naturally that would lose its flexibility of arbitrary placement. For example,

```
restart;
f2:=proc(v, 
        ord::{integer,NoUserValue}:=':-NoUserValue',
        {special::{integer,list,NoUserValue}:=':-NoUserValue'});

  print(':-ord'=ord, ':-special'=special);

end proc:
f2(x);
f2(x,3);
f2(x,special=5);
f2(x,special=5,3);
f2(x,3,special=5);

restart;
f3:=proc(v, 
         special::{integer,list,NoUserValue}:=':-NoUserValue',
         {ord::{integer,NoUserValue}:=':-NoUserValue'});

  print(':-ord'=ord, ':-special'=special);

end proc:
f3(x);
f3(x,5);
f3(x,ord=3);
f3(x,ord=3,5);
f3(x,5,ord=3);
```

There are too many variants to show them all here, sensibly.

You don't have to use the name "NoUserValue" as the default values.

Answer (score 3):

Use keyword arguments.

```
f:=proc(x,{op1::integer:=0,op2::{list,integer}:={}},$)

   if has([_passed],'op1') then
      print("op1 =",op1);
   else
      print("op1 not passed");
   fi;

   if has([_passed],'op2') then
      print("op2 =",op2);
   else
      print("op2 not passed");
   fi;

    #rest of code
end proc;
```

Now you can do

```
f(x,'op2'=[1,2,3])    
                        "op1 not passed"    
                       "op2 =", [1, 2, 3]
```

And

```
f(x,'op1'=99)
                          "op1 =", 99
                        "op2 not passed"
```

And

```
f(x)
                        "op1 not passed"    
                        "op2 not passed"
```

And

```
f(x,'op1'=99,'op2'=[1,2,3])
                          "op1 =", 99
                       "op2 =", [1, 2, 3]
```

And

```
f(x,'op1'=99,'op2'=19827)
                          "op1 =", 99
                         "op2 =", 19827
```

Make sure to use `'op1'=value` when calling, and not `op1=value`

Answer (score 3):

As others already mentioned one solution is using "*kwarg*" (keyword argument). You can also use `_passed` or `_rest`. You can read more in Maple help pages or Maple programming guide (https://www.maplesoft.com/documentation_center/Maple2021/ProgrammingGuide.pdf).

Here is just an example how you can use them. `_passed` is for when you want to say whatever that has been passed to your procedure, and `_rest` is for whatever that has been passed to your procedure except the ones that are already assigned to the parameters you mentioned inside the parentheses in front of `proc`. Let's say we want to define a procedure with 1 necessary argument and possible 2 optional arguments. If there are two optional arguments given, we assume the first one is always `option1` and the second one is `option2`, but if only one optional argument is given, then depending on if it is of type `integer` or not it will be `option1` or `option2` respectively.

To ask the number of passed or the rest of passed arguments you can use `_npassed` and `_nrest`. And the command `assigned()` checks if something is assigned a value or not. You can check if something is of a specific type, by `type(-,-)` or `- :: -`. So here is the simple code.

```
test := proc( x )
    local option1, option2:
    if _nrest = 2 then
        option1 := _rest[1]:
        option2 := _rest[2]:
    elif _nrest = 1 then
        if _rest[1] :: integer then
            option1 := _rest[1]:
        else
            option2 := _rest[1]:
        end if:
    end if:
    printf( "necessary argument is %a\n", x ):
    if assigned( option1 ) then
        printf( "option 1 is given and is %d\n", option1 ):
    end if:
    if assigned( option2 ) then
        printf( "option 2 is given and is %a\n", option2 ):
    end if:
end proc:
```

Here is a screenshot of the output of the above procedure for different inputs.

[image]